Appropriate Model for Pricing European Bond Option, Black or Bachelier?
Suppose an European embedded option zero coupon bond with par value $L$, strike price $X$, the maturities for embeded option and bond are $T_o$ and $T_b$, $T_o<T_b$, respectively. If we assume that the forward bond prices follows log-normal distribution, then by using the Black model, the price of call option at $t$, $t<T_o$, will be
\begin{align*}
C(t,P_F(T_o,T_o,T_b),X) &= P(t,T_o)\mathbb{E}_{T_o}\left\{\max(P_F(T_o,T_o,T_b) - X,0)\right\}\\
&= P(t,T_o)\left[P_F(t,T_o,T_b)\Phi\left(d_1\right) -  X\Phi\left(d_2\right)\right]\\
&= LP(t,T_b)\Phi\left(d_1\right) - P(t,T_o) X\Phi\left(d_2\right)
\end{align*}
where $P_F(t,T_o,T_b)$ is the forward bond price such that
\begin{equation*}
P_F(t,T_o,T_b) = L\frac{P(t,T_b)}{P(t,T_o)}
\end{equation*}
$\mathbb{E}_{T_o}\{\cdot\}$ denotes expectation in a world that is forward risk neutral with respect to $P(t,T_o)$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}_{T_o}\{P_F(T_o,T_o,T_b)\} = P_F(t,T_o,T_b) 
\end{equation*}
I am currently reading Howard Corb's book "Interest Rate Swaps and other Derivatives", on Chapter 5.3.1 on page 181, it discusses that

the lognormal distribution is more appropriate for modeling stock prices, because stocks with higher price tend to have greater price fluctuations.
the normal distribution is good assumption for interest rate, because there is no significant difference on volatility between higher rates and lower rates.

Because forward bond price is closely related to the interest rate, I am wondering, should I use the Bachelier model rather than Black model to valuate the embeded option price in a zero coupon bond?
P.S.
The Bachelier model assumes that the T-forward price of an asset at time $t$, $P_F(t)$ follows an arithmetic Brownian motion with volatility $\sigma_N$, such that
\begin{equation*}
dP_F(t) = \sigma_N dW(t)
\end{equation*}

I doubt Bachelier is a good model for ZC bonds, even as a quoting mechanism. Although Bachelier can be used for rates/yields since they have become negative in the past, the price of ZC bonds is always non-negative.

According to the paper "A Balck Scholes user's guide to the Bachelier model",  The Bachelier model assumes that the T-forward price of an asset at time $t$, $P_F(t)$ follows an arithmetic Brownian motion with volatility $\sigma_N$, such that
\begin{equation*}
dP_F(t) = \sigma_N dW(t)
\end{equation*} So I think, for Bachelier model, not the price can go negative, it is the price difference can go negative.

Actually, price changes can be negative with the lognormal distribution as well. The problem with the Bachelier / normal model is that the price itself can become negative, which for a bond is not possible.

Yes, you are right....

I’m voting to close this question because OP got convinced four hours ago that Bachelier for the bond price is not the appropriate model.

Note that we have the zero coupon  price $$P = e^{-yT_b}$$, so that $$lnP = -yT_b$$, where $y$ is the bond yield .  So if you believe yield follow a normal distribution , the zero coupon bond is lognormally distributed. Now as @AKDemy says, it doesn’t much matter what model you use for a single ATM option, but it seems that the lognormal assumption may be better if you are pricing options across a range of strikes.

Thank you for your replying, the reason that I asked this question is because I tried to calibrate Hull White 1F model using market prices of caps/swaptions. Because the Hull-White model is an arbitrage-free, mean-reverting normal model, I though maybe I should use hull white + Bachelier model to valuate caps/swaptions.

So now the question becomes: $\frac{dP_F}{P_F} = \mu dt + \sigma dz_t$ or $dP_F= \mu dt + \sigma dz_t$, which one is better for discribing the forward bond price

In theory it doesn't matter. You can use Black or Bachelier and the price will agree with each other, provided the Vols are appropriate (see this answer with Bloomberg screenshots).
It will depend if you use price or yield vol though, because yield can be negative, in which case Black is undefined. If you use price vol, black is perfectly fine and what Bloomberg OVME defaults to. That price will also match quotes you get from market makers (provided you get an IV and price quote).
The main problem you will have is that the market is very illiquid, and you will not get quotes for IV or prices on vendor platforms like Bloomberg. You can only infer IVs from related ETFs with "liquid" options.

You should not confuse OP. If by Bachelier you mean a model by which a bond price can become negative I am going to ask who on earth would sell a bond that has a negative price? Prices of assets cannot be negative.

I think using Bachelier model mean difference of forward bond price is normal distributed, not bond price

Thank you for your replying, the reason that I asked this question is because I tried to calibrate Hull White 1F model using market prices of caps/swaptions. Because the Hull-White model is an arbitrage-free, mean-reverting normal model, I though maybe I should use hull white + Bachelier model to valuate caps/swaptions.
